# Looping between file to store text Perl

Tags: perl

```
sub open_file {
    my @files = @_;
    my @file_text = ();

    foreach my $file(@files){
        open(my $fh, '<', $file);
        @file_text = <$fh>;
        close($fh);
    }
    return @file_text;
}
```

Hi there. There seems to be a problem with this coding particularly the `foreach` loop part.
`@files` is an array containing `@files = (abc.html bcd.htm zxy.html);` I would like to open all these html files and store the accumulative html texts in `@file_text` for further use.

However i am getting error :

```
readline() on closed filehandle $fh at source-1-2.pl line 36
readline() on closed filehandle $fh at source-1-2.pl line 36
readline() on closed filehandle $fh at source-1-2.pl line 36
```

Maybe i am getting three line of same error cause i am looping between 3 html/htm files.

Comment: `my @file_text = ();` is better written as `my @file_text;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps check if the `open` succeeded:

```
open(my $fh, '<', $file)
    or die "can't open $file: $!";
```

Comment: Thank you this helped to point the problem. Apparently the script cant find the file. However i do not know how to make it find the files which are in the directory ./DATA/

Comment: I recommend never using `||` in `open` calls, since it is easy to do something like `open my $fh, '<', $file || die $!` and never understand that it is wrong.

Comment: @TLP: Good point, @DeepakTivari: you could write `open(my $fh, '<', "/DATA/" . $file)`

Comment: hmm by putting a dot "./DATA".$file) it worked however not without the dot. Thank you all :D

Comment: @DeepakTivari `./DATA/` is just a more complicated way of saying `DATA/`. The period `.` represents the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `open` without checking the return value:

```
open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!;
#                        ^^^^^^^^^ this part
```

What has probably happened is the open failed, so the file handle was never opened.

Comment: You should also check the return value of [`close`](http://p3rl.org/close "perldoc -f close"). Alternatively you could use [autodie](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html "perldoc autodie").

Comment: @BradGilbert That's a far more obscure problem than failing to open a file. Besides, when the file handle goes out of scope, the file is automatically closed.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the points about **open** in other answers, the question asks "**...open all these html files and store the accumulative html texts in @file_text for further use.**". The code has the line `@file_text = <$fh>;`
 which will mean the `@file_text` only has the contents of the last file read. That line might be replaced with `@new_text = <$fh>; push @file_text, @new_text;` or `@new_text = <$fh>; @file_text = (@file_text, @new_text);`.